# C++ using std::set and getting a segmentation fault D:

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, set, valgrind

I have no clue what my error report in valgrind is telling me... but here are the parts of my code pertinent to the issue:

```
template<typename T>
struct CompareEvents {
public:
    bool operator()(const T a, const T b) const {
        return a.time < b.time ? true : false;
    } 
};


class EventManager {
public:
    void EventManager::SendEvent(int delay, size_t sender, size_t receiver, size_t eventId) {
        if (delay > 0) {
            eventQueue.insert(Event((GetTime() + delay), sender, receiver, eventId));  //line 55
        }
    }
private:
    std::set<Event, CompareEvents<Event>> eventQueue;
}
```

Event is just a simple struct which has four parameters (time, sender, receiver and ID).

Calling SendEvent from my test class results in a lovely seg fault... which looks like this (valgrind):

```
==998== Invalid read of size 8
==998==    at 0x40D544: std::_Rb_tree<Event, Event, std::_Identity<Event>, CompareEvents<Event>, std::allocator<Event> >::_M_begin() (stl_tree.h:493)
==998==    by 0x40D8C4: std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<Event>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<Event, Event, std::_Identity<Event>, CompareEvents<Event>, std::allocator<Event> >::_M_insert_unique<Event>(Event&&) (stl_tree.h:1261)
==998==    by 0x40C44B: std::__cxx1998::set<Event, CompareEvents<Event>, std::allocator<Event> >::insert(Event&&) (stl_set.h:419)
==998==    by 0x40ADE2: std::__debug::set<Event, CompareEvents<Event>, std::allocator<Event> >::insert(Event&&) (set.h:210)
==998==    by 0x40A130: EventManager::SendEvent(int, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) (EventManager.cc:55)
==998==    by 0x402D07: main (main.cc:28)
==998==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Umm... ugly? main.cc:28 is my SendEvent call, a simple:

```
EventManager::Instance()->DispatchEvent(3, 1, 1, 1);
```

(It's built as a singleton class, in case you are wondering about the Instance() method).

So that's my problem. I can't make heads or tails of it, but I dunno, am I botching the insert into my std::set? I haven't used sets before, so that might be it? Do I need to initialize something? I'm pretty confused...

Comment: Why did you only show the parts that *aren't* relevant ? If you have a problem with the set, show how you declare and initialize that set.

Comment: I think we'll also need to see your implementation of `EventManager::Instance()`.

Comment: Aren't? But they're the ones getting highlighted in the error report... and the reason I try to minimize the amount of code I copy-paste in to hear is because it's for a course, and they run plagiarism checks (not sure how far it extends, but, trying to be cautious).

Comment: `return a.time < b.time ? true : false;` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @GMan Awesome, I missed that :-))

Comment: @Fault: "`main.cc:28` is my SendEvent call, a simple:" *code that calls `DispatchEvent`*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing more info, here's a guess!

I would guess that the `EventManager` you're calling `SendEvent` on is `NULL`. The `valgrind` error is telling you that 0x10 is an address that valgrind has no clue about, and `0x10` is a nice round number, possibly a 16-byte offset into a structure (`EventManager`), but your pointer was `NULL`. `NULL + 0x10 = 0x10` on most platforms.

This is stupid easy to check: Let the program segfault in `gdb`, jump to the frame of the `SendEvent` call, and see if `this` is `NULL`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This was the problem. Since the class is supposed to be a singleton class, I should have been declaring my eventQueue as static! But because I wasn't, it was never getting constructed, and... eeyup.

Comment: SO should really give double rep for psychic answers. ;-P

Comment: I don't think I believe in the supernatural... much more likely that you're in my room, watching me program. But thanks again, regardless if you are watching me or not.